# Trigger click event in option directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to trigger click event on click of options. I can't use change event for some reasons.

Here's my code

```
.directive('itemOptions', [
            function() {
                return {
                    restrict : 'A',
                    template : "<option ng-value='item_id'>{{item_name}}</option>",
                    replace : true,
                    link : function(scope, element, attrs) {

                        element.on('click', function() {
                            //get element value
                        });                        
                    }
                }

            }
        ])
```

Click event is not firing...

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Please no change event only click event. thanks.

Comment: use `scope.$apply` inside the event handler

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
angular.element(element).bind('click',function(){
here get the element ... 
})
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering but still does not fire the click event.

Comment: Hi @Defyleiti , I am sorry for being late , and I created a plnkr for you it fires and logs on the page . http://plnkr.co/edit/ArTRvW8URGkakz2a5CNP?p=preview

Comment: Hi, I need to wrap it with select element. This is where it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you create a directive for such a basic template? 
You should read the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select#using-select-with-ngoptions-and-setting-a-default-value), and use `ng-model` on the select.

Comment: It's not really basic, this is just a skeleton of what I'm doing. I just remove parts which are not important for the question.

Comment: using a directive to store an `<option>` can't be really difficult, as an option is not a difficult component. I still think that you try to put your logic too far down the tree, and that this should be handled by the selectController rather than the option…

Comment: no worries, update the question when the issue is resolved, or when you have new problems :)